# How can I collapse Silverlight DataGrid Groups using MVVM?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, mvvm, grouping

I'm using MVVM in a Silverlight application. So I use a PagedCollectionView as property of my View Model to bind it to a DataGrid ItemSource. But I have this requirement: "all groups in the Grid should be collapse when the user control is loaded.". As I'm using a Page collection View I used this code:

```
     this.PinesView = new PagedCollectionView(this.Pines);
     PinesView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Operador"));                        
     PinesView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Marca"));
```

Now I have the code to collapse the groups, but the only piece of code I found needs to run over the UI, so It's kinda difficult to link it to my ViewModel because that collectionview is filled Async, so I don't know how to comunicate about the collection is already filled to the UI to run this code; or even better, how to send that collapse instruction from my ViewModel to the UI.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
public View()
{
 InitializeComponent();
 datagrid.LoadingRowGroup += new EventHandler<DataGridRowGroupHeaderEventArgs>(datagrid_LoadingRowGroup);
}

void datagrid_LoadingRowGroup(object sender, DataGridRowGroupHeaderEventArgs e)
{
 datagrid.LoadingRowGroup -= datagrid_LoadingRowGroup;

 foreach(CollectionViewGroup group in (datagrid.ItemsSource as PagedCollectionView).Groups)
 {
  datagrid.CollapseRowGroup(group, true);
 }
}
```